# copied the jdk to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ next to the default 1.6.0 one

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

How do I exactly copy the 1.7 JDK file to the location stated in the title, do I change the location of the file to download it when it requests me to download it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is OSX - the JVM downloads to  the where the installer says (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk) you do not change it. the thing you download is an installer app, run that and it will download the jdk and place it in the correct directory.

The old Apple supplied 1.6 version which is not now part of the OS is not in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ but is in /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk